# Filter elements by counting their relationship Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables, the typical master-detail, what I intend to do is obtain the master's records, while the registration number obtained by means of a where of the relationship is greater than n

I've been doing this until now

```
Master::withTrashed()
->with('details')
->withCount(['details' => function ($query) {

    $query->whereDate('date_init', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateString()); 
}]);
```

with this I get the master and its details with the given conditions, but there are teachers that the count of the relationship is 0, that I want to ignore. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked into `whereHas`? https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: @aynber Yes, but I understand that it is to add restrictions to the relationship, but if the condition is false it does not stop showing the master only shows the empty detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the following query:

```
Master::withTrashed()
    ->with(['details' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('date_init', '<', now());
    }])
    ->whereHas('details', function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('date_init', '<', now());
    })
    ->get();
```

The query literally means:

> Give me all `Masters`, also the deleted ones, which have at least one attached `Detail` with an initialization date in the past. Also eager load all attached `Details` which have been initialized in the past.

Answer (score 0):

```
Master::withTrashed()
->has('details')
->with('details')
->withCount(['details' => function ($query) {

    $query->whereDate('date_init', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateString()); 
}]);
```

Fixed whereHas to has, as pointed out by Namoshek.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is not what I explain in my question, your answer in no way eliminates the master with the count equal to 0;

Comment: Actually, it should be `has('details')` and then it does indeed eliminate the master. You'd need `whereHas('details', function ($query) { $query->whereDate('date_init', '<', now()->toDateString()); })` if you want to perform the existence query with an attached condition.